# Svn tortoiseto compare two verison of software

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have svn repoistory of the  project on which I am working in company's server. Today I got different version of software through zip files which I have extracted in my local folder in C drive. Now how will i compare between projects on svn repository and the one I have downloaded in my local folder. I am using SVN tortoise on windows platform. Now when i rightclick on my local folder it doesnt show merge or diff option. Please throw some light on it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With modern versions of TortoiseSVN, there's a fairly straightforward way of doing this:

1. Make sure that you're using TortoiseSVN 1.7.0 or later.
2. Make sure that your working copy has been upgraded to the 1.7 format.  If you right click on the working copy and it gives you the option "SVN upgrade working copy" then use that option.
3. Copy and paste the .svn directory from your working copy into the same part of the hierarchy of the version you got via Zip files.

You should now be able to use regular TortoiseSVN actions in the zip version, such as "Diff with previous version", etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to compare the two versions directly using a file/directory comparison tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).  You could then merge changes from the zipped archive into your SVN working copy.